cannot access vercel/postgres database with sql
i have a postresql db deployed on my vercel account. i used to be able to manage it with sql commands (import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres'). but now, even tough i connected it to the db and pulled the env files, i get "No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance." error.
i used to be able to create a table in my db with this code:
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request) {
    try {
        const result =
            await sql`CREATE TABLE Pets ( Name varchar(255), Owner varchar(255) );`;
        return NextResponse.json({ result }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

then, i started using prisma orm. when i try to use this code again after using prisma with the db, i started to get the error i mentioned. is it about prisma? like once you set up your db with prisma, you are not allowed to use sql commands?
